# method .map when running item.url stay with the last url on every iteration of the view while keeping changes from each of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to iterate on a group of elements, so far they iterate on render return, but for some reason when trying to use item.url on  but the elements stay with the last item.url path had read. how can make that each iteration use its own item.url instead just the last one from the array of objects.

```
On line 53 of ./CategoriesListContainer.jsx

class CategoriesListContainer extends React.Component {

  state = {
   redirect: false,
   }
   setRedirect = () => {
    this.setState({
     redirect: true
   })
  }

  render (){
    const ItemsApp =[
      {
        url: '/mail',
        title: 'Mailing',
        description: 'Esto es una descripcion de la carta a usar para el CSV mailing.',
        buttonClass: 'btn-success',

      },
      {
        url: '#',
        title: 'Excels',
        description: 'Esto es una descripcion de la carta a usar para otros modulos.',
        buttonClass: 'btn-success',
      },
    ];
    return(
      <SectionWrapper sectionTitle='Categories'>
        { ItemsApp.map(Item => {
          return (
            <CardWrapper
              key={ Item.title }
              customClass='card'
              description={ Item.description } 
              title={ Item.title }
            > 
              { this.state.redirect ? <Redirect to={ Item.url }/>: null }
              <Button onButtonClick={ this.setRedirect } customClass={ Item.buttonClass } title='Entra aqui' />
            </CardWrapper>
          );
        })}
      </SectionWrapper>
    );
  }
};
export default CategoriesListContainer;
```

I expect to click on each of the buttons and get to the page defined for its URL variable.

Answer (score 0):

In general you want something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ name: 'Colin' }, { name: 'Ricardo' }]
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    console.log(name)
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li
            key={item.name}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.name)}>
            {item.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fuhs1o).

Comment: Yeah, something like that, I'm new with js and jsx, and I didn't understand why is it that item.url on each component stays with the path of the last item.url that .map() pass through.

Comment: It shouldn't, but it's hard to tell from the code you posted.

Comment: Please post it in the question, not here.

Comment: It's likely because the `setState()` is taking some time to finish, by which time the loop has gone to the next item.

Comment: How could i fix this so it wont wait till the loop ended?

Comment: If you make a CodeSandbox I'll fix it for you.